# Uikit3 - call out modal programmatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, getuikit

Something wrong with UIkit3 modal.

I get to open it with simple command, as said in docs:

```
var modal = UIkit.modal($('#select-instrument'));
modal.toggle();
```

This does nothing. It returns Promise 'pending'

[image]

If afterthat I call `modal.toggle()` again, then it does show the window.

What am I doing wrong? How do I call modal from the first call?

Answer (score 2):

Finally, easiest way to open modal in UIkit was to do it myself, without UIkit js at all.

```
$('#select-instrument').addClass('uk-open').show();
```

And close:

```
$('#select-instrument').removeClass('uk-open').hide();
```

What's going on under the hood in UIkit for these simple actions I wouldn't even check.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply give the element ID to modal method OR jQuery object and it will do its job just fine in both cases.

I think that in your case, your modal ID will be probably incorrect. I believe that `UIKit.modal` returns undefined in your example image from console (but with wrong ID your modal shouldn't work at all, hmm). Does the modal exist on first call?

```js
var modal = UIkit.modal('#modal-id');
$('#toggleButton').on('click', function() {
  modal.toggle();
});
```

```html
<!-- UIkit CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.0.0-beta.35/css/uikit.min.css" />

<!-- UIkit JS & jQuery (not required by UIKit anymore) -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.0.0-beta.35/js/uikit.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.0.0-beta.35/js/uikit-icons.min.js"></script>

<!-- This is a button toggling the modal -->
<div class="uk-position-center">
  <button id="toggleButton" class="uk-button uk-button-default">Click for Modal</button>
</div>

<!-- This is the modal -->
<div id="modal-id" uk-modal>
  <div class="uk-modal-dialog uk-modal-body">
    <h2 class="uk-modal-title">Opened modal</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Id is correct. Because when I call it second time, modal opens. Finally easiest way was to call modal directly `$('#select-instrument').addClass('uk-open').show();` Works like a charm, UIkit js programmers screwed something again.

Comment: I don't think it's UIKit problem, have you tried logging the modal object after you call `UIKit.modal` ? I've never had such problem and I always use JS to open modal, as I need to run some other routines before it shows up